# Why was componentWillRecieveProps replaced with getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the reasons behind the use of getDerivedStateFromProps and why componentWillRecieveProps was deprecated. After having read some articles, I came into conclusion that one of the reasons componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated is that it is synchronous and it can be a problem if we try using asynchronous code in it. **Is it because componentWillRecieveProps has to wait until the finish of the asynchronous code in it and block rendering?** Secondly, as far I understood, getDerivedStateFromProps is asynchronous and static meaning we cannot use this, in turn, this.setState. **Since getDerivedStateFromProps is asynchronous, meaning not blocking, why we cannot use api calls or setState in it?**

Comment: We can't use setState in it because it doesn't have access to the components instance, *this*.